# How can I know if someone has logged into my account in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, security

In Windows 7, is there a way to know if somebody has logged into my account when I was absent?

Specifically, is it possible to know if a person with administrator privileges somehow entered my account (i.e. in order to get into my email etc.)?

Comment: Why would I need to login?  I'd just pull your hard drive out, plug it into mine, and copy your email/files/super secret stuff without ever logging into your PC.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Recommended Method EDITED (Please Upvote Susan Cannon down below):

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> button + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `eventvwr.msc`.
2. In event viewer, Expand Windows Logs, and select System.
3. In the middle you’ll see a list with Date and Time, Source, Event ID and Task Category. The Task Category pretty much explains the event, Logon, Special Logon, Logoff and other details.

The events will be called **Winlogon**, with Event ID **7001**.

The event Details will contain the **UserSid** of Account logging on, which you can match with a list obtained from Command Prompt using:

```
wmic useraccount
```

Hope this helps!

---

To see a list, run "PowerShell", and paste the following script into its window:

```
Get-EventLog system -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon `
    | ? { $_.InstanceId -eq 7001 } `
    | ? {
            $sid = $_.ReplacementStrings[1]
            $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ($sid)
            $objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
            $_ | Add-Member -Force -type NoteProperty -name User -value $objUser.Value
            return $true
        } `
    | ft -Property TimeGenerated,User
```

---

You'll have a bunch of system logins; they are normal.

**What you will be looking for:**
Event ID 7001 - Winlogon.

Under the Details Tab, Look for **UserSid**

An indication of a login will look like this: (win 8.1) This will probably be different in win 7

```
+ System
- EventData
   TSId        1
   User Sid    A-2-8-46-234435-6527-754372-3445
```

Then open up command prompt by right clicking start button and selecting it.

Type in "wmic useraccount" and match the SID with the preceding username in the long list that comes up.

```
C:\Users\Superuser>wmic useraccount
AccountType  Caption  Description Disabled  Domain  FullName InstallDate
LocalAccount  Lockout  Name PasswordChangeable  PasswordExpires 
PasswordRequired  SID   SIDType  Status
512  ComputerName\Administrator   Built-in account for administering the
computer/domain  TRUE  ComputerName TRUE   FALSE  Administrator   TRUE
FALSE  TRUE A-2-8-46-234435-6527-754372-3447   1  Degraded

512  ComputerName\Superuser TRUE  ComputerName TRUE   FALSE  Superuser   TRUE
FALSE  TRUE **A-2-8-46-234435-6527-754372-3445**   1  Degraded
```

We see from the list that **Superuser** is the account matching the SID.

Comment: Thanks! I actually see 4 events for each successful logon (by myself): "Logon - 4624", "Special Logon - 4672", "Logon - 4648", "Logon - 4624", all at the same time.

Comment: Note:  `wmic useraccount get name,sid` produces a much more manageable output.

Answer (score 5):

[Pathfinder's answer](https://superuser.com/a/726971) of checking the event log will let you know if someone logged into your computer.  However, that will not tell you if they logged into another computer with your account.  You would have to check that machine, or a Domain Controller to see logins from other machines.

As for emails, that's another story.  As an Exchange admin, I *can* read the emails of anyone in our organization.  Honestly, I don't know if that access is logged anywhere.  I'm sure it would be, but that would be only available to Exchange administrators.

Comment: @Pang: Thanks for adding the link and fixing the punctuation of the contractions, but “mail” and “email”, like “air”, “water”, “sand” and hundreds of others, are valid collective (mass / non-count) nouns.  Keltari’s use of the singular (collective) “email” was fine, as in [“Gentlemen don’t read each other’s mail.”](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/henry_l_stimson_295174) and [*You’ve Got Mail*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0128853/).

Comment: @Scott Yeah [I guess you're right](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/211726). Feel free to edit that back. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a corporate network, this won't work. Corporations have all sorts of automatic logins. I looked at either event 4648 or 4624, and logons are successfully logged even when people are not in the office (and no, no one is sneaking in to log in to PCs). There are thousands of them. I just logged in to the PC one time, and there are 10 activity sources under 4624. I did not log in 10 times. There were 12 logins yesterday under 4648, but no one touched the PC at all that day. So that's not an accurate list of real person logins.

If you want the REAL login info, go to **System** under Windows Logs, and filter on event **7001**. This is successful **WINLOGONS**. This corresponds to user logins, and excludes system logins behind the scenes. Using this, I found the proper list of real live people user logins to the PC.

But unfortunately it still doesn't tell me WHO logged in. Our company doesn't keep those records as it would be a mile long every day. I look at UserID in the details, and the UserID for me logging in just now matches every other UserID under every login shown. And this is not my PC, so some of the logins are definitely not mine. So I don't know about that part.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Ultimate connected to a domain, but logging in locally.

I just went through the Security event log and realized that the only time I could find "legitimate" logons were for ID ***4648***.  This worked for me.